# Share monitor from laptop to pc

Tags: windows-10, fedora, screen-sharing

I would like to use my laptop, which is running windows 10 and I would like to share it's screen on my PC which is running Fdora 28.
Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

There are many options and products for sharing the screen.

The simplest would be to install on both computers a VNC sharing product.

One of the best is [TeamViewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/).

Comment: install skype and make a call to share screen. Or use remote desktop connection to connect to another PC directly.